# Why is ABRecordCopyCompositeName NULL, and what's an alternative?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I find that in development, in my contacts, ABRecordCopyCompositeName returns NULL for a few records, but when I view my contact list normally, I don't see any missing names.

What's a standard alternative label to use if ABRecordCopyCompositeName returns a NULL? Also, what causes the NULL values to exist in the first place?

(EDIT: title corrected)

Strangely:

- The count at the bottom of the "Contacts" iPhone app states 119 contacts.
- I counted all entries - all 119 are there and have names.
- [ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook) count] returns 116, not 119.
- Counting each entry from ABAddressBook, I get 116, *including* the 3 null entries.

So, on top of three null entries, I'm missing 3 more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still looking for a better answer, but until then, here's what I've found:

- The NULL records are due to records imported from Exchange. They show as having a name, and if you edit them and save them (through the UI) the name shows up correctly, but until then, I can't seem to get a name out of the record.

The three 'missing' records are still confusing me. I believe they are also imported from Exchange, but just not included in the ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource request.

My work-around was to not fill out table cells directly from ABAddressBook, but to copy the entries into an array first, so that the counts are correct. As I get further toward release, I may circle back to this routine and change it so that very large address books will not cause memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not all contacts have stored firstname and lastname just email or some other field... For some reason apple is sorting based on this.. The empty compositename with email address "example@example.com" will appear below the contact named "Edward"... So it makes sense to create a fallback-thingy: if compositename is empty then look for email-address